# How to always display profile name in Chrome?

Tags: profile, google-chrome

In Chrome, when using a profile, there is an avatar menu button on the top-right corner. The first time the browser starts after profile is created, the profile name is displayed with the avatar, but after some seconds, it disappears, we can only see it after clicking the button.

[avatar+profile-name] (After some seconds, profile-name disappears) ↓
[avatar]

I want it to show always, how can I do that?

(Sorry, I can't post images yet)

Answer (score 0):

This function is held within the chrome theme it self so no there is no simple way to do this without writing your own theme.

Comment: Hello, this is not sufficient enough info for a good answer. You should state e.g. where it is in the theme.